# Call to a member function esAdmin() on null

Tags: laravel

Tras configurar roles de usuario y Middleware me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Call to a member function esAdmin() on null
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $user=Auth::user();
    if($user->esAdmin()){
        return view('nagusiaAdmin');
    }else{
        return view('nagusia');
    }
});
```

Middleware/EsAdmin.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user=Auth::user();

        if(!$user->esAdmin()){
            return redirect('/');
    }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: en el modelo "user" existe el método "esAdmin()"?

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que estas preguntando si el usuario es administrador, cuando el usuario no esta loggeado, por lo tanto tienes que preguntar primero si existe el usuario **$user** y si el usario es admin **$user->esAdmin()**

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $user=Auth::user();
    if($user && $user->esAdmin()){
        return view('nagusiaAdmin');
    }else{
        return view('nagusia');
    }
});
```

Middleware/EsAdmin.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user=Auth::user();

    if($user && !$user->esAdmin()){
        return redirect('/');
}
    return $next($request);
}
```